# Ctypes Wrapper and unit-testing

Tags: python, tdd

I wish to wrap a C library for use in python. I also wish to implement my class using test driven development. Here are the two classes I've written so far and their interface. There is a whole bunch of classes just like these that I need to wrap.

```
class FunctionWrapperForOurLibrary:
    def __init__():
        pass

    def __call__():
        pass

class OurOpener(FunctionWrapperForOurLibrary):
    def __init__(self, our_library):
        self.our_library = our_library
        our_library.OurOpen.argtypes = [c_char_p, c_char_p]
        our_library.OurOpen.restype = OUR_ERROR

    def __call__(self, admin_path, company_path):
        status = self.our_library.OurOpen(admin_path, company_path)
        if status.lRc:
            raise Exception("Unable to connect to database due to this error: "+str(status.lRc))

class OurDataCreator(FunctionWrapperForOurLibrary):
    def __init__(self, our):
        self.our_library = our_library
        our_library.OurCreateData.argtypes = [c_int]
        our_library.OurCreateData.restype = POINTER(OUR_DATA)

    def __call__(self, our_structure_type):
        data = self.our_library.OurCreateData(our_structure_type)
        return data
```

First question, do I aid readability by including an interface class? I realise its not needed. What about my object and class names. Any suggestions on how I might make these clearer?

Secondly, how might I write a class which contains these functors? A class which is unit testable?

The best I can come up with is something along these lines:

```
class Our:
    def __init__(self, our_open, our_data_create, ...):
        self.opener = our_open
        self.data_create = our_data_create

our_open = OurOpener(our_library)
our_data_create = OurDataCreator(our_library)
our = Our(our_open, our_data_create)
```

but I will have a large number of functors to pass to the class constructor.

Any better of doing this?

**UPDATE:**

```
class Our:
    def __init__(self, our_library):
        self.our_library = our_library
        our_library.OurOpen.argtypes = [c_char_p, c_char_p]
        our_library.OurOpen.restype = OUR_ERROR
        our_library.OurCreateData.argtypes = [c_int]
        our_library.OurCreateData.restype = POINTER(OUR_DATA)

    def open(self, admin_path, company_path):
        status = self.our_library.OurOpen(admin_path, company_path)
        if status.lRc:
            raise Exception("Unable to connect to database due to this error: "+str(status.lRc))

    def create_data(self, our_structure_type):
        return self.our_library.OurCreateData(our_structure_type)
```

Comment: This design declares the ctypes signatures repeatedly and requires instantiating an object just to call a darn function (once per place that calls it to boot, unless one explicitly passes the object around). There may be reasons for it, but I doubt they're any good - I'd say it's bollocks.

Comment: You're right! I sometimes get carried away with the notion that a class should do only one thing. Anyway, would you approve of the class in the UPDATE section of my original post?

Comment: I still don't see what you need a class for. It's not like there's any state, or anything to be encapsulated that couldn't be at module level.

Comment: our_library is the return value from windll.LoadLibrary in the ctypes module, therefore I need to mock it in order to test that my wrapper uses it in the correct way. It needs to be created outside the thing I'm testing. Can you provide a quick example of how I might do this without the use of a class? Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: That's the thing, I'm not sure on the best unit testing approach, or I'd have answered. Mocking it ought to be possible, but it may fragile and/or bad style - I'm no guru.